# groupby to show same row value from other columns

Tags: pandas

[image]

After groupby by "Mode" column and take out the value from "indicator" of "max, min", how to let the relative value to show in the same dataframe like below:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'relative.csv')
Grouped = df.groupby('Mode')['Indicator'].agg(['max', 'min'])
print(Grouped)
```

[image]

(from google, maybe can use from col_value or row_value function, but seem be more complicated, could someone can help to solve it by easy ways? thank you.)

Comment: Please post your data as reproducible dataframes. We can't do anything with pictures.

Comment: Can you have more than 2 Modes? What should be the output in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps, using `groupby` and `idxmin()` or `idxmix()`:

```
# Create a df with the min values of 'Indicator', renaming the column 'Value' to 'B'
min = df.loc[df.groupby('Mode')['Indicator'].idxmin()].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'Indicator': 'min', 'Value': 'B'})
print(min)
#   Mode  min  B
# 0    A    1  6
# 1    B    1  7

# Create a df with the max values of 'Indicator', renaming the column 'Value' to 'A'
max = df.loc[df.groupby('Mode')['Indicator'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'Indicator': 'max', 'Value': 'A'})
print(max)
#   Mode  max  A
# 0    A    3  2
# 1    B    4  3

# Merge the dataframes together 
result = pd.merge(min, max)

# reorder the columns to match expected output
print(result[['Mode', 'max','min','A', 'B']])
#   Mode  max  min  A  B
# 0    A    3    1  2  6
# 1    B    4    1  3  7
```

Comment: Seems like the most rationale thing to do as no logic was provided

Comment: Actually I think the A/B column names are poorly chosen and the real logic might be [as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75492460/16343464)

Comment: Agreed, question and logic is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Mode": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
        "Indicator": [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        "Value": [6, 5, 2, 3, 6, 8, 7],
    }
)

new_df = df.groupby("Mode")["Indicator"].agg(["max", "min"])

print(new_df)
# Output
      max  min
Mode
A       3    1
B       4    1
```

Here is one way to do it with [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from Python standard library's [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module and Pandas [at](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) property:

```py
from itertools import product


for row, (col, func) in product(["A", "B"], [("A", "max"), ("B", "min")]):
    new_df.at[row, col] = df.loc[
        (df["Mode"] == row) & (df["Indicator"] == new_df.loc[row, func]), "Value"
    ].values[0]

new_df = new_df.astype(int)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
      max  min  A  B
Mode
A       3    1  2  6
B       4    1  3  7
```

Comment: Thanks all sirs give me a hand on above the awesome answer for me. That are the good method to reduce my steps solve the problems. Real appreciated again.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is unclear, there is no real reason why you would call your columns A/B since the 6/3 values in it are not coming from A/B.

I assume you want to achieve:

```
(df.groupby('Mode')['Indicator'].agg(['idxmax', 'idxmin'])
   .rename(columns={'idxmin': 'min', 'idxmax': 'max'}).stack()
   .to_frame('x').merge(df, left_on='x', right_index=True)
   .drop(columns=['x', 'Mode']).unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
     Indicator     Value    
           max min   max min
Mode                        
A            3   1     2   6
B            4   1     3   7
C           10  10    20  20
```

Used input:

```
  Mode  Indicator  Value
0    A          1      6
1    A          2      5
2    A          3      2
3    B          4      3
4    B          3      6
5    B          2      8
6    B          1      7
7    C         10     20
```